CREATE TABLE permissions required to append Pyspark dataframe to SSMS table
I am using AWS glue to extract some data from RDS, parse it into some other format and push it back to RDS.
The RDS user I use has SELECT and INSERT permissions on tic.Example. However, when I try to insert into it, I get the following error:
df_new_691.write \
                .format("jdbc") \
                .option("url", jdbc_url) \
                .option("dbtable", "tic.Example") \
                .option("user", db_properties_logwriter['user']) \
                .option("password", db_properties_logwriter['password']) \
                .option("driver", db_properties_logwriter['driver']) \
                .mode("append") \
                .save()
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3323.save.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'SystemLogsClient'. 

How can I append data to the table without requiring CREATE TABLE permissions?
